# Memcpy for converting array to vector

Tags: c++

I have a function which I want to use to convert an array of doubles to a vector of doubles:

```
std::vector<double> ArrayToVector(const double* arr, int length)
{
    std::vector<double> vec(length);
    memcpy(&vec[0], &arr[0], length);
    return vec;
};
```

But when I run:

```
int main()
{
    double* x = new double[3];
    x[0] = 2;
    x[1] = 4;
    x[2] = 6;
    std::vector<double> y = ArrayToVector(x, 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        std::cout << y[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the output:

```
0 0 0
```

Rather than

```
2 4 6
```

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is memcpy expect a size in bytes, not number of elements so you need to multiply that third argument by `sizeof(double)` but really what you should be doing is use the constructor for vector which expects two iterators like so :

```
std::vector<double> y(x, x + 3);
```

this way you don't even need to worry about sizeof and it's shorter!

Alternatively you could use `std::copy` (as mentioned in my comment/the other answer but that's longer for no reason)

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `memcpy` to copy into a `std::vector`, it is less efficient and error prone.

It is less efficient because when you construct or resize a vector it fills new elements with a value-initialized element (unless you provide one), which is 0 for arithmetic types. But that initialization is unnecessary because you then overwrite the values. That initialization may be cheap, but it is not free.

`std::vector` has a constructor that takes two iterators, as others already mentioned, that copies the input range. This constructor avoids the unnecessary default-initialization before copying.

`std::vector` also has `assign` and `insert` member functions that take two iterators and copy the input range efficiently. `v.append(beg, end)` is `v.insert(v.end(), beg, end)`.

---

In my opinion, using `memset`, `memcpy` and `memmov` in C++ code is always a mistake.

These functions are implemented by the standard C library and hence lose input argument type/alignment information (because they take `void*`). Before switching to the most appropriate SIMD version they need to check the alignment and size of the arguments at run-time. The unaligned beginnings and ends are handled by non-SIMD instructions.

Whereas a C++ compiler knows the alignments and sizes from the type and generates appropriate SIMD instructions inline without those alignment and size checks that C library functions do. Again, those checks may be cheap, but they are not free.

C++ algorithms like `std::copy`, `std::copy_backward`, `std::fill` and container copy functions which take two iterators use these C primitive functions for POD types automatically.

C++ initializer expressions like `{}` in `double buf[N] = {};` do `memset` for you, but again, in a more efficient and a less error prone manner.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
memcpy(&vec[0], &arr[0], length*sizeof(double));
```

or better yet, use:

```
int main()
{
    double* x = new double[3];
    x[0] = 2;
    x[1] = 4;
    x[2] = 6;

    std::vector<double> y(x, x+3);    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        std::cout << y[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: or better yet std::copy, or even better initialize the vector with two iterators (i.e. arr and arr+length)

Comment: @Borgleader, That's really the only answer here. It negates the need for `ArrayToVector` in the first place. You end up needing less characters of code than calling the function even.

Answer (score 1):

memcpy copies bytes. So you have to specify the number of bytes (not the number of doubles) you are going to copy.

```
memcpy(&vec[0], &arr[0], length * sizeof( double ) );
```

Nevertheless this approach is bad. It is better to define the vector the following way

```
std::vector<double> ArrayToVector(const double* arr, int length)
{
    return { arr, arr + length };
}
```

Or

```
std::vector<double> ArrayToVector(const double* arr, int length)
{
    std::vector<double> vec( arr, arr + length );
    return vec;
}
```

Take into account that you need to free allocated memory for the array. You could use for example smart pointer `std::unique_ptr` for the allocated array.